# post build command fails, doesn't make sense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

```
<Command xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">PostBuild.exe /project:"$(ProjectPath)" /target:"$(TargetPath)"</Command>
```

This seems like a tautology? In PostBuild do PostBuild?

I don't want to remove it unless I understand what it does, but I can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? What type of project is it?

Comment: @BerndLinde The syntax of the command is incorrect. It's just a standard C# class library. Not an executable. If anyone knows a reference on these "command" things I've never seen, that would help.

Comment: I've never heard of a "Command" element in MSBuild. Can you give more context? Is it just a property that is run in an Exec task?

Comment: Well, I found out that PostBuild.exe is a proprietary software piece.
But I would still like to know what this element thingy is.